# Zend says this URI is not valid

Tags: php, zend-framework, url

I am generating a feed using Zend Framework.

When I am setting a link like the one below, I get an error

```
$feed = new Zend_Feed_Writer_Feed;
$url = "http://www.example.com/search?s=chris|gayle|pics&device=1"
$feed->setLink($url);
```

I searched through Zend_Uri.php and Http.php, I was not able to figure out the problem.

> exception 'Zend_Feed_Exception' with message 'Invalid parameter:
>   parameter must be a non-empty string and valid URI/IRI'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is not allowed. Use `%7C` instead.

For more info, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters

To encode a url use `urlencode`. This will make sure all characters are correctly encoded into a standard URI.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: This feed is for a search result. Users might search for something with a space character. What is the best character to replace space character with?

Comment: Space should be `+`. Updating my answer with more info.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to urlencode values in your URI

Correct URI will be "http://www.example.com/search?s=chris%7Cgayle%7Cpics&device=1"

Just use urlencode() or rawurlencode(); to encode URI parts.

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/search?s=".urlencode("chris|gayle|pics")."&device=1"
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) | is not a valid symbol.

To have those characters in url, you must encode your url. You could use [urlencode](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) method to do this.